# Is this possible in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Class `Color`:

```
public class Color {

    public static const Black:uint = 0x000000;
    public static const White:uint = 0xffffff;

    public static const Red:uint = 0xff0000;
    public static const Blue:uint = 0x0000ff;
    public static const Green:uint = 0x008000;

    public var code:uint;
    public var family:String;

    public function Color():void {}

}
```

`Main.as`:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main() {
        var red:Color = new Color();
        red.code = Color.Red;
        trace(red);
    }
```

How to make `trace(red)` output 0xff0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `toString()` for the class.

```
override public function toString():String {
    return "Ox"+code.toString(16);
}
```

On a side note: Your `public function Color()` should not return `void`, instead leave it without return type. Also, your `red` variable in `Main` is not initialized. The code should read `var red:Color=new Color();`

Comment: `toString()` of the class haven't existed yet so `override` should be remove

Comment: Any object inherits `toString()` from `Object`.

Comment: That's the getter. I forgot to ask: What about setter?

Comment: `toString()` does not have a corresponding setter. Moreover, `toString()` is not even a getter as is, rather a function called on special circumstances, and its specilaty is just that it's called by Flash engine if you query an object of your class without a qualifier.